# Javascript/ I am stuck with changing back to the original background

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and am now doing a homework assignment.
I need to find how to remve a background image from an element after the mouse leaves the element.
I wrote the function code, Dogimgleave(), and it does not update the HTML.
Here is the code, please help me...

```
<img class=size src = "Images/Dog.jpg" alt="Dog!" onmouseover="Dogimgon()" onmouseleave="Dogimgleave()">

function Dogimgon(){
    document.getElementById("centertext").style.backgroundImage="url('Images/Dog.jpg')";
}
function Dogimgleave() {
    document.getElementById("centertext").style.backgroundColor="#65F0B6"; 
}
```

Comment: What is the _original background_ here?

Comment: Use background instead of backgroundColor.

Comment: @Seblor Setting a background-color does not remove the image.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the functions do not interact with the `<img />`, but with another element `centertext`. Where is that element in your code?

Comment: @Seblor They do, but setting backgroundColor does not remove the backgroundImage which was set earlier.

Comment: @ChrisG Ah, my bad, then

Answer (score 1):

You're leaving the background image set as an image, so you won't see the background colour.  You can clear the image like this...

```
function Dogimgleave() {
    var ct = document.getElementById("centertext");
    ct.style.backgroundImage = ""; // this removes the background image
    ct.style.backgroundColor="#65F0B6"; 
}
```

Comment: Oh, I did not notice that background image was covering background color. Thank you so much ! It is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `backogrund-image` and `background-color` simultaneously one will cover the other one. You should have only one of them set at any time:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("centertext");
function Dogimgon(){
    elem.style.backgroundImage = "url('Images/Dog.jpg')";
    elem.style.backgroundColor = "";
}
function Dogimgleave() {
    elem.style.backgroundImage = "";
    elem.style.backgroundColor = "#65F0B6"; 
}
```

This can be of course simplified to setting just the `background` property:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("centertext");
function Dogimgon(){
    elem.style.background = "url('Images/Dog.jpg')";
}
function Dogimgleave() {
    elem.style.background = "#65F0B6"; 
}
```

Or alternatively you may have color always set (it would be visible through transparent parts of the image however) and alter only the image:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("centertext");
elem.style.backgroundColor = "#65F0B6"; 
function Dogimgon(){
    elem.style.backgroundImage = "url('Images/Dog.jpg')";
}
function Dogimgleave() {
    elem.style.backgroundImage = "";
}
```

By the way, unless you task is to do that exactly in JavaScript, you may easily achieave the same result with pure CSS:

```
#centertext {
    background: #65f0B6;
}
#centertext:hover {
    background: url('/Images/Dog.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Wow, I just start learning it and there are many ways of setting up! Thank you so much! I learned a lot today!

Comment: I would like to ask further question about setting up background. When I use backgroundImage property, is it any other way of changing it as other Image or color if I don't remove the background Image? Or it has to be removed the background Image before I want to set up with other image or color?

Comment: Basically setting any style to a new value overrides the old value (unless the cascading rules give precedence to some other definition, like some `!important` CSS rule). If you want several background to stack you have to do that explicitly, by separating them by a comma when setting the `background` property: `elem.style.backdround = 'url(bg1.jpg), url(bg2.jpg)';`